# Why am I getting blank output when parsing this HTML?

Tags: html, perl

I use `LWP::UserAgent` and `HTML::Parser` to send an HTTP request and I want to retrieve a matching string in the output. Here is the output:

```
OK - Number of results: 1
Name: Catalina:type=Manager,path=/xxxxxx,host=localhost

modelerType: org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean

sessionMaxAliveTime: 29034

duplicates: 0
maxInactiveInterval: 28800

entropy: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager@6fefa3e7

activeSessions: 3

sessionCounter: 7
```

I want to retrieve the value of `activeSessions`. I tried this:

```
if ( $response->content()=~/activeSessions:/ ) {
    print ("$1 OK\n");
}
```

but the output is blank. I also tried this:

```
my $parser = HTML::Parser->new( 'text_h' => [ \&text_handler, 'dtext' ] );
$parser->parse( $response->decoded_content );

sub text_handler {
    chomp( my $text = shift );

    if ( $text =~ /activeSessions:/i ) {
        print "Matched: $1\n";
    }
}
```

but the output is still blank. Why?

Comment: `$1` is only set if you create a capturing group with `()`: `print $1 if $foo =~ /(regex)/;`

Answer (score 3):

instead of

```
if ( $response->content()=~/activeSessions:/ ) {
   print ("$1 OK\n");
}
```

try

```
if ( $response->content()=~/activeSessions:\s*(\d+)/ ) {
   print ("$1 OK\n");
}
```